# Changing animation-timing-function with Element.animate() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to animate a HTML **div** using JavaScripts built in **Element.animate()** function. Sadly, I haven't found a way to change the **animation-timing-function** that is getting parsed along with other timing-settings as the second argument of the **Element.animate()** function.

My **JavaScript** code so far:

```
// This variable declares all keyframes of the animation.
const animationKeyframes = [
    {transform: 'translateY(-100%)'},
    {transform: 'translateY(0%)'}
]

// This variable contains all animation options.
// There should be a way to specify a timing-function.
const animationOptions = {
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1
}

// Runns the animation for the div that I want to animate.
Element.animate(animationKeyframes, animationOptions)
```

The code above executes without any errors and moves the **div** from the top to the bottom of the page at a **linear speed**. However, I want the speed to **ease-in** at the beginning and to **ease-out** at the end of the animation.

I tried:

- adding `animationTimingFunction: 'ease-in-out'` to the **animationTiming** constant
- adding `animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;` to the **CSS** properties of the **div**

My only source so far: [Mozilla Docs: Element.animate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)

Comment: In the 'I tried' section on the first point I meant: animationOptions constant. I'm sorry fro that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the 'easing' prop in your animationOptions:

```
const animationOptions = {
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1,
    easing: 'ease-in-out'
}
```

Other values that can be used in the easing property are: 'ease', 'linear', 'ease-in', 'ease-out', and 'ease-in-out'.